# How to delete row after i select the row and press the button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

**Screenshot**

[image]

```php
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['View']) && $_GET['View']=="HistoryEntry"){    
    echo '    
              <h2>History Of Entries</h2>               
                <table id="table" class="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="col">#</th>
                        <th scope="col">Date In</th>
                        <th scope="col">Date Out</th>
                        <th scope="col">Rfid</th>
                        <th scope="col">Plate #</th>  
                     </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>';

 global $connection;  
$query = "SELECT * FROM history_entries";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query); 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

    echo '<tr>
                        <th scope="row">'.$row['Entry_ID'].'</th>
                        <td>'.$row['Date_in'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row['Date_out'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row['Acc_rfid'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row['Plate_num'].'</td>


          </tr>';

}

         echo '          </tbody>
                  </table>
                  <center>
                  <button>Delete</button>
                      </center>
                <div class="line"></div>';
} 

?>

?>
```

```js
$("#table tr").click(function() {
  $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass("selected");
});

$("#Sample").click(function() {
  var value = $(".selected th:first").html();
  value = value || "No row Selected";
});
```

As you can see this my codes, i already know how to select the row and get the ID but cant pass the ID "value" to php in order to do the delete function in database. can i use here $.POST function here? or is it better to use GET function here but i think it wouldn't be secure.

Comment: you can use jquery post method with a variable named id. 

        `$(document).ready(function() {
        $.post( "delete.php", {
          id: <?php echo "your id here" ?>;
        }, function( data ) {
          
        });
      });`

Comment: Don't overthink it. The simplest way is to have a click on a row change the button's `href` to `http://server/table.php?action=deleterow&id=x` or similar, where `x` is the row's ID. Then just handle the parameters with PHP, i.e. delete the row and send back the table.

Comment: then i'll use the GET method? what if the user change that action="" or id="", i would prefer the more secured way. @ChrisG

Comment: @EphraimJosephDizon A determined user can still change anything about your client side code they want; don't worry about it. If you don't want the deletion url to be visible in the address bar, use php's `header("Location: table.php");` to redirect after deleting the row. (also: stackoverflow expects you to do tons of research before asking here. you are a beginner, which means by definition that any question you have can probably be answered by other resources. stackoverflow is a last resort)

Comment: @ChrisG then the buttons will be in every row of the table? that has a unique ID num of that row.

Comment: @EphraimJosephDizon No, you only need one button. I told you to change its `href` when a row is selected.

Comment: i already did tons of research but those research wont work, im just finding another way other than GET method, anyway thank you sir for helping me, i appreciate your help. @ChrisG

Comment: Maybe a stupid question but if you do `isset($_GET['View']) && $_GET['View']=="HistoryEntry"` and `isset($_GET['View'])` is false , won't you get an error with `$_GET['View']=="HistoryEntry"` because `$_GET['View']` isn't "isset"?

Comment: And to anwser your question, can you get your `Entry_ID` when you select a row? The idea should be the following :1/ You select a row. 2/ You get the current selected row id. 3/ On click "delete" you send the "current selected id" to your "delete.php" file using Ajax 4/ You delete the row according to your id

Comment: @MickaelLeger Actually there is more View = "Something".whenever i use this get method i always use another parameter because of the chances that the user will change the value in the url.

yes. i can get the entry_id, but the problem i can't pass the value from js to php, in order to execute the delete the function.

Comment: I post an anwser with Ajax if you want to give it a look :)

Comment: @MickaelLeger okay okay thank you for you help :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it without get param :

1/ Your FRONT :

HTML (just an example)

```
<table>
    <tr id="row_id">
        <td>Data 1</td>
        <td>Data 2</td>
        ...
    </tr>
    ...
</table>

<button id="delete_row" type="button">Delete</button>
```

JS / jQuery

```
var current_row_id = "";

// You select the row
$("#table tr").click(function() {
    $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass("selected");

    current_row_id = $(this).attr("id"); // Here you get the current row_id
});

// You delete the row
$("#delete_row").on("click", function() {
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "delete.php",
         data: {"id" : current_row_id }, // You send the current_row_id to your php file "delete.php" in post method
         dataType: 'json', // you will get a JSON format as response
         success: function(response){
             // you do something if it works       
         },
         error: function(x,e,t){
             // if it doesn't works, check the error you get
             console.log(x.responseText);
             console.log(e);
             console.log(t);
         }
    });
});
```

2/ Your BACK

PHP "delete.php" file

```
<?php

$id = $_POST['id']; // You get the 'current_row_id' value

// Now you do your DELETE request with this id :
$sql = "DELETE ... WHERE id = :id"; 

etc...

$result = array(); // You can prepare your response and send information about what you did

$result['row_deleted'] = $id;
$result['message'] = "The row with id = " . $id . " was deleted with success";
$result['type'] = "success";
//etc....

echo json_encode($result); // You send back a response in JSON format
```

3/ Back to the FRONT

Your ajax call, the success part :

```
success: function(response){
    // You can display a success message for example using your response :

    alert(response.message); // You will get 'The row with id = {the row id} was deleted with success' here for example
},
```

Is it what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple Ajax request

```
var data = {
   rowId: 1
};

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",// GET|POST
  url: 'delete.php', // Where you want to send data like url or file
  data: data, // this is what you want to send to server, in this case i send data with id = 1 to server
  dataType: 'json' // here we say what data type we want "json"
  success: function(response) {
      alert(response);
  }, // this is the callback were u will get response from your server
});
```

delete.php here is how u can handle this ajax

```
$rowId = htmlspecialchars($_POST['rowId']);
if ($rowId) {
    global $connection;
    $query = "DELETE FROM history_entries WHERE Entry_ID = " . $rowId;
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query); 

    $response = array(
        'success' => true 
    );
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;

} else {
  echo json_encode(array('success' => false));
  exit;
}
```

Hope this will help you to understand how to use Ajax